# PL SQL Function

Tags: oracle

I have below error:

> Failure occurred in Bl9StackablePromotionModule::createPromoPeriodMap.
>   Duplicate promotions found for subscriber id 123 , offer id=123, offer
>   instance 123, charge code=ABC, effective date=20150707

Now I want to fetch subscriber, offer id, offer instance, charge code, effective date only.

For that I have created below function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTIONGetdyna1 ( att  IN VARCHAR, attName IN VARCHAR ) RETURN VARCHAR IS 
    start_index INTEGER := 0; 
    end_index INTEGER := 0; 
    retVal VARCHAR(100); 
    tmpAtt VARCHAR( 4000 ); 
    tmpAttName VARCHAR( 4000 ); 

BEGIN 
    tmpAtt := UPPER( att ) ; 
    tmpAttName := UPPER( attName ); 


    start_index := INSTR( tmpAtt , tmpAttName ); 

    IF( start_index = 0 ) 
    THEN 
        RETURN 'NOTFOUND'; 
    END IF; 

    start_index := start_index + LENGTH( tmpAttName ); 
    end_index := INSTR ( tmpAtt , '#' , start_index  ) ; 

    retVal := SUBSTR( att, start_index  + 1, end_index - start_index  - 1 ); 

    RETURN retVal; 

END Getdyna1; 
/
```

I am running below query

```
select GETDYNA1(error_description,'subscriber')subscriber,cycle_seq_no from error ;
```

But it is not giving me "subscriber" value.

Comment: what do you mean by `'#'`? why you don't just `retVal := SUBSTR( att, start_index  + 1 );`?

Comment: Check if you really have `#` in `tmpAtt`.